# How to iterate over values of an array in nodejs synchronously

Tags: node.js, loops

I want to iterate over an array in a synchronous manner

```
let arr= new Array([10,20,30]);
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  htmldata+=`<h1>${arr[i]}</h1><br/>`
}
console.log(htmldata)
```

What I get output is

```
<h1>10,20,30</h1><br/>
```

what I expect to store in `htmldata` is (in string format)

```
<h1>10</h1><br/><h1>20</h1><br/><h1>30</h1><br/>
```

Tried from other stackoverflow answers, which gave me a way only to get the indices correctly, but not the array values

```
var funcs = [];
htmldata=``
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    funcs[i] =   function() {
      console.log("My value: " + i,arr[i]);
      htmldata+=`<h1>${arr[i]}</h1><br/>`
    };
}
for(let i=0;i<3;i++) funcs[i]();
console.log(htmldata)
```

output:

```
My value: 0 [ 10, 20, 30 ]
My value: 1 undefined
My value: 2 undefined
<h1>10,20,30</h1><br/><h1>undefined</h1><br/><h1>undefined</h1><br
```

How to do this?

Comment: your array contains 1 item, which is an array of 3 items. What do you expect this `new Array([10,20,30]);` to do?

Comment: @njzk22 Oh yes, Thank you, I was too dumb to make that silly mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your iteration logic, but in your array declaration:

```js
let arr = new Array([10, 20, 30]);
console.log(arr);
```

See the problem? It's an array of arrays, not an array of numbers.

There's rarely ever any reason to use use `new Array` anyway. Just use an array literal alone, and you'll get what you're looking for:

```js
let htmldata = '';
let arr= [10,20,30];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  htmldata+=`<h1>${arr[i]}</h1><br/>`
}
console.log(htmldata)
```

Or, even better, use `.map`.

```js
let arr = [10,20,30];
const htmldata = arr
  .map(num => `<h1>${num}</h1>`)
  .join('<br>');

console.log(htmldata)
```